# php three dropdown filter

Tags: php

I have a table called classifieds and it contains the following:

- id
- title
- description
- state_id
- city_id
- cat_id

This is dynamically populated from database.

```
<form name="theForm" method="post" action="advanced_search.php">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
    <select name="categories" >
        <option value=""> Select Category</option>
    </select>
    <select name="state" >
        <option value=""> Select state</option>
    </select>
    <select name="city" >
        <option value=""> Select city</option>
    </select>
    ...
```

When I select a category and click search, the result for that category will show up.  If I select a category and a state then I want it to filter to a specified category and state.  The same should occur if a city is selected.

EX: If I select employment category in Minneapolis city, then the search should be filtered to all employments in that city.

With the code bellow it requires to select all the dropdowns to get the filter working. 
What if I want to show all results of a category in a specified state?  What if I want to filter by category only?

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $categories = $_POST['categories'];

    $select = "SELECT * FROM classifieds";
    $where = " WHERE ( authorized = '1')";

    $where .= " AND (cat = '" . $categories . "' AND state_id = '" . $state . "' AND city_id = '" . $city . "')";

    $where .= " AND (state_id = '" . $state . "' )";
    $where .= " AND (city_id = '" . $city . "' )";
    $q = $select . $where . ' ORDER BY date DESC';
```

Can someone walk me through this?

Comment: Asking for a "walkthrough" is not a good fit for Stack Overflow; could you focus your question on the specific problem that's currently preventing your from progressing?

Answer (score 2):

Only add the where clauses if they've selected something:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM classifieds";
$where = " WHERE ( authorized = '1')";
if($categories) {
    $where .= " AND (cat = '" . $categories . "' )";
}
if($state) {
    $where .= " AND (state_id = '" . $state . "' )";
}
if($city) {
    $where .= " AND (city_id = '" . $city . "' )";
}
$q = $select . $where . ' ORDER BY date DESC';
```

Comment: Did you get rid of `$where .= " AND (cat = '" . $categories . "' AND state_id = '" . $state . "' AND city_id = '" . $city . "')";`  ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide complete code for generating the query.

Comment: That works only if I select categories, state and city. But if I don't select a city then the result shows 0. Same ting if I select only categories without selecting state and city.

Comment: You didn't change your form code did you? My code assumes that the "Select..." options have a value that is an empty string.

Comment: That's how I've done if($categories !="") {
    $where .= " AND (cat = '" . $categories . "' )";
}  and so on. I've been playing with this all day, but I can't get what I want.

Comment: Try echoing out $categories, $city, and $state at the top of your script and make sure the appropriate variables are empty. I use code like this all the time, so the basic scheme is sound.

Comment: The values inside variables are fine. I think I just don't how to combine the AND, OR

Comment: What "OR" are you talking about?

Comment: Like, using only AND the user has to select a category, a state, a city, which your code works fine for this, but if the user select only a category, a state then there is no result.

Comment: Don't put an OR in the query. The logic to determine which fields to search is in the PHP. The code only adds where clauses for the fields you want to search based on whether an option was selected in the search form. If a city, for example, was not selected, then there should be no reference to the city_id database column in the query.